# Is there a specific term for the association of certain verb(s) with certain nouns (as direct objects)?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Or vice versa. Or perhaps a name for the pair itself?

For example:

- *hold* an *opinion*
- *make* a *complaint*
- *offer* an *apology*

Also, where might I find a list of such pairs?

---

EDIT: I chose my title wording randomly. I have no idea whether 'cognate verb' is the correct term for these things. However, I've just found out that 'cognate objects' are a defined class in linguistics, so perhaps my choice of words was inappropriate. I'm going to leave the title as it is, anyway.

Comment: I am troubled by your use of the definite article. Surely most nouns have several cognate verbs. As well as *pose a questions* one could also *ask/formulate/fire/devise/delay/circumvent etc*.

Comment: That's true. However, some don't. Question was a bad example. When one want's to complain, one *makes* a complaint, etc. I'll remove the question line and substitute it with something else.

Comment: And is 'cognate verb' the correct term? That's partly my question.

Comment: My favorite examples of verb + noun collocation are "to attempt suicide" and "to commit suicide." Those seem to be about the only two things one can do with suicide.

Comment: @Silenus One could *threaten/feign/consider/* suicide.

Comment: @WS2 - That's true, but I don't think you're comparing like with like. In terms of the act of an individual killing themselves, one does not say that they *carry out/execute/implement/do/perform* suicide, etc.

Comment: @Charon There must be confusion here. I didn't suggest any of those!

Comment: @WS2 - What I meant was that your comment directed to Silenus was not a fair response because your counter didn't relate to the same circumstances. In the specific case of someone killing themselves, there is only one collocation in common usage, *commit suicide*. Therefore, his comment was a valid one. You countered that one could *threaten/feign/consider* suicide. However, those verbs don't refer to the act of killing onself, they refer to other actions. I tried to support Silencus argument that *commit* is the only collocation used by suggesting other plausible but unused possibilities.

Comment: @Charon I've rather lost track of what we are trying to prove here. But if it's the correct name of such a verb, I'm afraid I can't help.

Comment: @WS2 - Yes, me too. Was just continuning the conversation! Thank you for contributing and for pointing out the initial flaw in my question.

Comment: Careful, because things like "make a complaint" can also be "file a complaint", "register a complaint" etc. "hold an  opinion" can be "have an opinion". So, there are usual collocations and there are words that just don't normally go together. Nabokov made use of this: Bend Sinister is the title of one of  his novels, and unless you know heraldry, you might miss it entirely.....as I did in my early twenties. Compiling lists is a bad idea as there are too many possibilities.

Comment: So, you get people saying things like: "Well, I googled it and could not find it". There are tons of collocations that are perfectly acceptable but not yet "out there". And thank goodness for that. Otherwise, we'd already be robots....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These phrases are sometimes called "collocations". I don't know of a word for one element in the collocation.

Comment: One is a collocate of the other.

Comment: Yes, and when any term, whatever it is, doesn't "go" with another, we say they do  not collocate.  But this can get complicated very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by others, the name for the phenomenon you've isolated is ***verb noun collocation*** or ***verb + noun collocation***.

If you google these phrases, you should be directed to various sites which give examples. I know of no master list, but you could probably start to compile one yourself.

Comment: I think it's something one interiorizes over time. Making a list is futile though perhaps for an ELLer, it might help but many of these things can take many different forms: hold an opinion, have an opinion, articulate an opinion, express an opinion, but probably not, in that vein, disgorge an opinion, though literarily anything can be worked out......